# How to insert multiple records from a trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I am new to MySQL.
I want to create a trigger that will insert multiple records into `table B` after a record is inserted into `table A`.

The record inserted in `A` has a field `NUM` (type `INT(4)`) and I want to insert records into `B` with values from `X + 1` to `NUM`, where `X` is the highest number in `B`. I know that `NUM` does not exist in `B` because the `INSERT` is using `IF EXISTS`.

I tried to use `WHILE` loop but got a syntax error - it looks like MySQL does not allow `WHILE` in a trigger.

I was successful in inserting a single record with the value `NUM` but I can not figure out how to insert all the other records.

Comment: It still unclear like *Murder Mystery* as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: First, let me correct the explanation in that I amusig IF NOT EXIST to find out if there is a record with the value NUM in table B.
Second, maybe one can start by explaining to me why can't I use WHILE in the trigger? how can I do loops in the trigger (in MySQL)

Comment: To further clarify my problem: a record is inserted in table A with field Num=10. In table B the highest key is 6. I want to insert 4 records into table B with key = 7, key =8, key = 9, key = 10

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem which was mostly due to syntax of handling global variables and not creating a set inside a trigger.
Here is the code that will do what I wanted:

-- Full Trigger DDL Statements
-- Note: Only CREATE TRIGGER statements are allowed
DELIMITER $$

USE `q`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `q`.`event_AUPD`
AFTER INSERT ON `q`.`event`
FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one

BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

```
select LastNumberWaiting from A where 
            institution = new.institution and
            branch = new.branch and
            idQueue = new.queue into @ids;

ins_loop: LOOP

    set @ids := @ids + 1;
    if @ids > new.idLast then
        set done := TRUE;
    end if;

    IF done THEN
        LEAVE ins_loop;
    END IF;

    insert into B values (@ids);   # B has only one column 'id' in this example

END LOOP;
```

END$$